# How to get the same sorting result for this pattern

Tags: sort

When I use `sort -n -k 2 -r` on a text like this one:

```
último  12
últimos 5
única   27
único   227
úteis   2
útil    1
```

I get the expected result as you can see:

```
único   227
única   27
último  12
últimos 5
úteis   2
útil    1
```

Do you guys know if it is possible to get this working for the second column of a pattern like this ??

```
(zelar,12)
(zero,1)
(zes,1)
(zeze,12)
(ziza,2)
(zo,1)
(zona,6)
```

Comment: Is it sufficient to set the field separator to `,` i.e. `sort -t, -n -k 2 -r`?

Comment: @steeldriver thank you, it worked like a charm :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `-t,` to your `sort` command to make it use comma as the field separator. 
(You can add it to the command anywhere except between the `-k` and the `2`.) 
Note that this will not grant any special significance to the parentheses,
so, if you have some rows with parentheses and some without,
then lines where the number in the second column are equal will sort like this:

```
z,…
a,…
9,…
 ︙
2,…
10,…
1,…
(z…),…
(a…),…
```